# What does the HTTP error 410 mean?

Tags: http, http-status-codes

Recently, I was trying to download a file, and I got the following error from `wget`:

> Error 410:  Gone

What does this error code mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error code 410 means that the target file used to exist, but is gone  permanently.

Unlike the 404 Not Found error, it means the file did exist at one time - a 404 error usually means the file never existed.

It also means that the resource in intentionally unavailable - for example, a business stopped selling a product/service or file on a file sharing service was removed for a ToS violation.

Source: [CheckUpDown - Error 410](https://www.checkupdown.com/status/E410.html)